# Where methods (Clear, ForEach, Where, etc.) of powershell array are defined?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-core

According to the [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7) about arrays in PowerShell, several methods are defined for arrays, for example Clear(), ForEach(), Where(), etc. Following code tested these methods:

```
$arr = 1..2
$arr.Clear()
$arr.Length

write "--------------------------------------------------"
$arr = 1..2
$arr.ForEach({$_ + 1})

write "--------------------------------------------------"
$arr = 65..90
$arr.Where({($_ % 2) -eq 0})
```

Output:

```
2
--------------------------------------------------
2
3
--------------------------------------------------
66
68
70
72
74
76
78
80
82
84
86
88
90
```

Fine! And, methods such as ForEach() have many overloads that are not tested here.

But where these methods are defined? I mean, What is the class that contains the definition of these methods? As far as I know, these methods are not defined in .net core. (I use PowerShell 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clear()` is part of the `IList` interface implemented by `System.Array`, which is the base type for collections (`System.Object[]`) in PowerShell.

To see all native methods available, use:

```
$arr.PSObject.Methods
# or
Get-Member -InputObject $arr -MemberType Methods
```

However: The `Where()` and `ForEach()` "[magic](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/)" methods were introduced in v4 and are actually PowerShell-specific **extension** methods (as more performant alternatives to `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object`), defined in `System.Management.Automation.EnumerableOps`. Have a look at the [source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/859890374afd529211e657c7f0a8718387f187c2/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Operations/MiscOps.cs):

```cs
internal static object Where(IEnumerator enumerator, ScriptBlock expressionSB, WhereOperatorSelectionMode selectionMode, int numberToReturn)

internal static object ForEach(IEnumerator enumerator, object expression, object[] arguments)
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes! I accepted it. Thank you again. I just posted a new question about PowerShell, can you give me some suggestion? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711177/why-host-ui-rawui-readkey-method-captures-a-not-really-pressed-enter-key)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you state *As far as I know, these methods are not defined in .net core. (I use PowerShell 7)*? Really:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion | Out-Default
$arr = 1..2
$arr.GetType() | Get-Member -MemberType Methods -Static
```

> ```
> Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
> -----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
> 7      0      3
>
>
>    TypeName: System.Object[]
>
> Name            MemberType Definition
> ----            ---------- ----------
> AsReadOnly      Method     static System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[T] …
> BinarySearch    Method     static int BinarySearch[T](T[] array, int index, int length,…
> Clear           Method     static void Clear(array array, int index, int length)
> ConstrainedCopy Method     static void ConstrainedCopy(array sourceArray, int sourceInd…
> ConvertAll      Method     static TOutput[] ConvertAll[TInput, TOutput](TInput[] array,…
> Copy            Method     static void Copy(array sourceArray, array destinationArray, …
> CreateInstance  Method     static array CreateInstance(type elementType, int length), s…
> Empty           Method     static T[] Empty[T]()
> Equals          Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
> Exists          Method     static bool Exists[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] match)
> Fill            Method     static void Fill[T](T[] array, T value), static void Fill[T]…
> Find            Method     static T Find[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] match)
> FindAll         Method     static T[] FindAll[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] match)
> FindIndex       Method     static int FindIndex[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] match…
> FindLast        Method     static T FindLast[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] match)
> FindLastIndex   Method     static int FindLastIndex[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] m…
> ForEach         Method     static void ForEach[T](T[] array, System.Action[T] action)
> IndexOf         Method     static int IndexOf(array array, System.Object value), static…
> LastIndexOf     Method     static int LastIndexOf(array array, System.Object value), st…
> new             Method     System.Object[] new(int )
> ReferenceEquals Method     static bool ReferenceEquals(System.Object objA, System.Objec…
> Resize          Method     static void Resize[T]([ref] T[] array, int newSize)
> Reverse         Method     static void Reverse(array array), static void Reverse(array …
> Sort            Method     static void Sort(array array), static void Sort(array keys, …
> TrueForAll      Method     static bool TrueForAll[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] mat…
> ```